# Bootstrap 3 - jQuery is not defined Error?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I get this error when viewing my Bootstrap website with the FF Error Console

Error: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
Source File: `http://localhost/cap3boot/js/bootstrap.js`
Line: 6

All my JS files are linking to the correct directories.

Drop-down menus seem to work ok. Should I be concerned? Any ideas?

Comment: Is jQuery actually being included, e.g. in a script tag, before bootstrap.js is running? It appears that Bootstrap is depending on jQuery being there and not finding it

Answer (score 9):

You need to include the jQuery JS file before you include bootstrap.js. It can't be afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the problem. It was something really simple.

The two js files for HTML shim were not linked correctly, causing the error.

This is before

```
<script src="../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
```

After. Fixed.

```
<script src="assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
```